# Naive string search algorithm - average time

Tags: algorithm, search

I'm studding Naive string search algorithm (aka brute force algorithm). I know that, there exists other more efficient algorithms, but as I'm starting from basic, currently I'm interested only in this algorithm. 
And I have a question, as follows:
**What is the average time complexity (ϴ) for this algorithm?**
I have found that best and worst cases have respectively ϴ = N,  ϴ = M*N

Comment: Are all the letters in your strings generated in a uniformly random manner? Also, are they always of the same length? Alternatively, if the strings are words of a natural language, or data generated by some process, the ϴ-estimation may be different.

Comment: Also have you looked at the explanation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Na.C3.AFve_string_search)? If not, just use that. If yes, please specify what is unclear there.

Comment: Text to search (N) is randomly generated. It has an alphabet of 256 characters (byte buffer),

Comment: What about text to search for? Is it also randomly generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment to the question, it seems that the *N* text characters are uniformly randomly generated. For this setting, brute force's average time is *O(N - M)*, irrespective of the way the search string is generated. (Note that [Wikipedia states *O(N + M)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Na.C3.AFve_string_search), but we can actually deduce *O(N - M)* using the following analysis. See also [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~jiang/cs141/string.pdf)).

Consider the iteration where the search string is matched against the text at position *i* of the text. For any search string, each character of the search string has a probability *p = 255/256* of not matching the character of the search string. Say we define that a "success" is *not* matching. Then the number of attempts until success is a [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with [expected *(1 - p) / p = O(1)* failures until success](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Expected_number_of_failures_before_the_first_success).

So, for position *i*, the expected cost is *O(1)*. By [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity), we need now to sum over all relevant *i*. There are *Θ(N - M)* such *i*.